# Android - change Date Format to dd/mm/yy

Tags: java, android, date, date-format

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(calendar.getTime());
```

I'm trying to get the current date but in a format of DD/MM/YY, but it gives me MM/DD/YY 
Any suggestions about how to fix it?

Comment: You can get date and change its structure manually

Comment: Which Android version are you using?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `DateFormat` class and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String currentDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would like to reverse the date format.

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = fmt.parse(dateString);

SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
return fmtOut.format(date);
```

Hoping it will be helped.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate
.now
(
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" )
)
.format
(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uu" )
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## *java.time*

For a date only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use `LocalDate`.

A time zone is required to determine the current date. For any given moment, the date may by “tomorrow” in Japan while still “yesterday” in Mexico.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Generate a string with text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

Generate a string with text in your custom format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the current date but in a format of DD/MM/YY, …

Don’t. Trust that the user knows his or her locale best, and the locale data built into Java know the proper date format for that locale best. While 24/04/20 may be a fine format for your locale, on devices in other locales a different format is likely to be preferred.

Using java.time, the modern Java date and time API:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT);
    LocalDate d = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(d.format(dateFormatter));
```

BTW in many locales including Yiddish, Gallegan, Indonesian, Uzbek, Tajik, Somali, Malay, Italian and New Zealand English the output will be what you said you wanted:

> 24/04/20

I do recommend that you use java.time for your date work. `DateFormat` is a notoriously troublesome class, and `Calendar` is poorly designed too. Both are long outdated. And java.time is so much nicer to work with.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.